# Proving Borel Regularity

Tags: measure-theory, outer-measure

I have been studying general measure theory from Mattila's Geometry of Sets and Measures in Euclidean spaces. I am stuck on proving the Borel regularity in exercise 1. The question is as follows:

> Let $\nu$ be a countably additive non-negative set function on a
> $\sigma$-algebra, $\mathcal{A}$ of subsets of $X$. Show that it can be
> extended to a (outer) measure, $\nu^{*}$ on $X$ defined as:
> $$\nu^{*}(A) = \inf \{ \nu(B) : A \subset B, B \in \mathcal{A} \}$$
> Moreover, if $\mathcal{A}$ is contained in the Borel $\sigma$-algebra,
> then $\nu^{*}$ is a Borel regular measure.

I have proved that it is a (outer) measure on $X$. I am struggling to prove that it is Borel regular. In particular, I am unable to show it is even a Borel measure. My guess is to use Theorem 1.7 in the book.

Comment: What is wrong with taking $B_n\in \mathcal{A}$ such that $A\subset B_n$ and $\nu(B_n)\leq \nu^*(A)+1/n$, then taking $B=\cap_n B_n$?

Comment: @d.k.o. Isn't the first condition in the definition of a Borel regular measure that the measure should be Borel? If $\mathcal{A}$ is contained in the Borel $\sigma$-algebra, that doesn't necessarily imply that every Borel set is $\nu^{*}$-measurable.

Also, how does proving regularity and the paragraph after Theorem 1.4 get me there as you suggested?

Comment: @AhsanAli Yeah. You need to show that $\nu^*$ satisfies the definition in 1.5(3), i.e., each Borel set is $\nu^*$-mble and for every $A\subset X$, there is a Borel set $B$ s.t. $A\subset B$ and $\nu^*(A)=\nu^*(B)$.